# SQL CONTAINSTABLE does not return all the expected results

Tags: sql, full-text-search, fulltext-index, full-text-catalog

I have a table with just 2 columns Id (identity) and lastname(nvarchar). I applied a fulltextIndex WITH ACCENT_SENSITIVITY = OFF for dutch --> 1043 on lastname with an empty stop words list and added 2 records:

insert into  [UserProfile] values  ('hoopman')
insert into  [UserProfile] values  ('koopmans')

when i do:

SELECT *
from CONTAINSTABLE(UserProfile, Lastname, '"man*"',  LANGUAGE 1043)

I only get koopmans.

but if I do

SELECT *
from CONTAINSTABLE(UserProfile, Lastname, '"hoopman*"',  LANGUAGE 1043)

I do get hoopman.

Here is the script to reproduce the scenario

```
USE [master]
GO
/****** Object:  Database [Tests]   Script Date: 11/01/2023 13:43:25 ******/
CREATE DATABASE [Tests]
 WITH CATALOG_COLLATION = DATABASE_DEFAULT
GO
ALTER DATABASE [Tests]SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 150
GO
IF (1 = FULLTEXTSERVICEPROPERTY('IsFullTextInstalled'))
begin
EXEC [Tests].[dbo].[sp_fulltext_database] @action = 'enable'
end
GO
ALTER DATABASE [Tests]SET ANSI_NULL_DEFAULT OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [Tests]SET ANSI_NULLS OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [Tests]SET ANSI_PADDING OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [Tests]SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [Tests]SET ARITHABORT OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [Tests]SET AUTO_CLOSE OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [Tests]SET AUTO_SHRINK OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [Tests]SET AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS ON 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [Tests]SET CURSOR_CLOSE_ON_COMMIT OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [Tests]SET CURSOR_DEFAULT  GLOBAL 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [Tests]SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [Tests]SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [Tests]SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [Tests]SET RECURSIVE_TRIGGERS OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [Tests]SET  DISABLE_BROKER 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [Tests]SET AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS_ASYNC OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [Tests]SET DATE_CORRELATION_OPTIMIZATION OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [Tests]SET TRUSTWORTHY OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [Tests]SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [Tests]SET PARAMETERIZATION SIMPLE 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [Tests]SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [Tests]SET HONOR_BROKER_PRIORITY OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [Tests]SET RECOVERY FULL 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [Tests]SET  MULTI_USER 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [Tests]SET PAGE_VERIFY CHECKSUM  
GO
ALTER DATABASE [Tests]SET DB_CHAINING OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [Tests]SET FILESTREAM( NON_TRANSACTED_ACCESS = OFF ) 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [Tests]SET TARGET_RECOVERY_TIME = 60 SECONDS 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [Tests]SET DELAYED_DURABILITY = DISABLED 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [Tests]SET ACCELERATED_DATABASE_RECOVERY = OFF  
GO
EXEC sys.sp_db_vardecimal_storage_format N'Tests', N'ON'
GO
ALTER DATABASE [Tests] SET QUERY_STORE = OFF
GO
USE [Tests]
GO
/****** Object:  FullTextCatalog   Script Date: 11/01/2023 13:43:25 ******/
CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG [MyCatalog] WITH ACCENT_SENSITIVITY = OFF
AS DEFAULT
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[UserProfile]    Script Date: 11/01/2023 13:43:25 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserProfile](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1000000,1) NOT NULL,
    [Lastname] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_UserProfile] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
ALTER DATABASE [Tests]SET  READ_WRITE 
GO
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON  dbo.UserProfile (
    lastname LANGUAGE 1043
) KEY INDEX [PK_UserProfile]
WITH 
    CHANGE_TRACKING = AUTO, 
    STOPLIST=OFF
;
GO
```

then

```
insert into  [UserProfile] values  ('hoopman')
insert into  [UserProfile] values  ('koopmans')


SELECT *
from CONTAINSTABLE(UserProfile, Lastname, '"man*"',  LANGUAGE 1043)
```

thx a lot!

expecting hoopman and koopmans and gettign only koopmans when doing

```
SELECT *
from CONTAINSTABLE(UserProfile, Lastname, '"man*"',  LANGUAGE 1043)
```